# What is the difference between Remote Provisioning and Self-Service Site Provisioning

Tags: office-365, self-service, remote-provisioning

I am looking to use one of these techniques for site provisioning.

Both look very similar to me (having read a couple of blogs online), when would i use one over the other and are there any major limitations of either?

I will be using SharePoint 2013 on Office365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote Provisioning.

> Remote provisioning is model where we actually do the template system
>   outside of the SharePoint by using the new SharePoint app patterns. In
>   this case we would be using provider hosted pattern to provide
>   customizable sub site creation experience for the end users of the
>   SharePoint.

Very good explanation over here [Site provisioning techniques and remote provisioning in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

The "Self-service site creation" feature allows users who have the "Use Self-Service Site Creation" permission to create Site Collections in defined URL namespaces. Site collection is different with Sub-site.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/04/04/self-service-site-provisioning-using-apps-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768020.aspx